# Assigned form value into var in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have a html form below:

```html
<label class="sr-only" for="phone">Phone Number </label>
<input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="eg. 123456XXXXXXXX" class="phone form-control" id="phone">
</div>
<div class="f1-buttons">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-next">Next</button>
</div>
```

When the user fills in the form, the form value will be auto assigned in the script below:

```
<script>var data = "{ \"phone\":\"--this will get value from phone ID field\", \"tenantID\":\"0\" }"; .....</script>
```

Tried using the `document.getElementById("phone").value;` but it is not working. Any have suggestions how to achieve this?

```js
      
            var data = "{ \"MSISDN\":\"document.getElementById("phone").value\", \"tenantID\":\"0\" }";
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.withCredentials = true;

        xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
          if (this.readyState === 4) {
         console.log(this.responseText);
          }
        });

        xhr.open("POST", "https://api/v1/uat/user");
        xhr.setRequestHeader("accept", "application/json;charset=UTF8");
        xhr.setRequestHeader("content-type", "application/json");
        xhr.setRequestHeader("api-key", "12345565");
        xhr.setRequestHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
        xhr.send(data);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset>
  <h4>Please fill phone Number:</h4>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="sr-only" for="phone">Phone Number (123456789xxx) </label>
<input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="eg. 123456789xxx" class="MSISDN form-control" id="phone">
</div>
<div class="f1-buttons">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-next">Next</button>
</div>
</fieldset>
```

I edited my question, the phone number field is to call an API response using post method in body request. What I want to do is, when user filled up the phone number will POST to the API URL to get a response if valid the response will print in the next form

Thanks

Comment: `document.getElementById("phone").value` should work. Try providing a [mcve]. Preferably as a [live demo](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).

Comment: "but not working" — This is a [very poor description of the problem](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/)

Comment: Thanks for the response, I edited my question

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> var data = "{ \"MSISDN\":\"document.getElementById("phone").value\", \"tenantID\":\"0\" }";
> ```

Putting some JavaScript source code inside a string literal is just going to make a string literal containing **that source code** and not the result of executing it.

Generating JSON by hand is a poor idea anyway. The value might contain special characters that would break it.

Create an object. Add a value to that object. Then use a library function to encode it.

```
var data = {
    MSISDN: document.getElementById("phone").value,
    tenantID: "0"
};
var json = JSON.stringify(data);
```

Comment: Hi @Quentin, I got Bad request on this line `xhr.send(data);`

Comment: @Bireon — It's impossible to tell why based on that information. We know nothing about the API.

Answer (score -1):

You are assigning the JSON into a variable `var data = "{ \"phone\":\"--this will get value from phone ID field\", \"tenantID\":\"0\" }"`. So, you can access directly to `data` as the following snippet shows:

```js
console.log(data)
```

```html
<script>var data = "{ \"phone\":\"--this will get value from phone ID field\", \"tenantID\":\"0\" }"</script>
```